# Filtering elements of array on the basis of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array as follows:

```js
data = [
    {
      "startDate": "2021-08-18T00:00:04.498059"
      "endDate": "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889"
    },
    {
      "startDate": "2021-08-18T00:00:04.498059"
      "endDate": "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889"
    }
    ]

    newArray = [];
    this.data.foreach(element => {
       if((element.startDate - element.endDate) > 7) {
           this.newArray.push(element);
       }
    })
```

I want to traverse the above array and check if difference between startDate and endDate is greater than 7 days for any element, than push that element to a new array.

Because of the date format I don't know my approach is correct or not. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Simple JavaScript logic.

- Calculate time difference in millisecond between start date and end date.
- Convert the time into days by dividing with (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24).

Logic for (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) => 1000 ms = 1 second, 60 seconds = 1 minute, 60 minute = 1 hour, 24 hours = 1 day.

```js
const data = [
    { "startDate": "2021-08-18T00:00:04.498059", "endDate": "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889" },
    { "startDate": "2021-08-18T00:00:04.498059", "endDate": "2021-08-26T00:00:04.4962889" },
    { "startDate": "2021-08-18T00:00:04.498059", "endDate": "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889" }
];
const newArray = [];
data.forEach(element => {
    const diffTime = new Date(element.endDate) - new Date(element.startDate);
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
    if (diffDays > 7) {
        newArray.push(element);
    }
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the one you are looking for:

```js
let data = [
{
  startDate: "2021-08-18T00:00:04.498059",
  endDate: "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889",
},
{
  startDate: "2021-08-11T00:00:04.498059",
  endDate: "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889",
}
]


let newArray = [];
data.forEach(element => {
let start = new Date(element.startDate)
let end = new Date(element.endDate)
if((end-start)/1000/60/60/24 > 7)
      newArray.push(element);
   })
   console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: This will only work when dates are in the same month. I also think Date.parse() is redundant here.

Comment: @jna, thank for pointing that out. Fix it and update the code!

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
{
  "startDate": "2021-08-18T00:00:04.498059",
  "endDate": "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889"
},
{
  "startDate": "2021-08-18T00:00:04.498059",
  "endDate": "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889"
}
]
const newData = [];
data.forEach(element => {
  const startDate = new Date(element.startDate);
  const endDate = new Date(element.endDate);
  const difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  if (difference > 604800000) {
    newData.push(element);
  }
}
);
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

`You can check using moment.js library`

```js
let data = [
{
  startDate: "2021-08-18T00:00:04.498059",
  endDate: "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889",
},
{
  startDate: "2021-08-11T00:00:04.498059",
  endDate: "2021-08-19T00:00:04.4962889",
}
];
let newArray = [];
for(let i of data){
let end= moment(i['endDate']);
let start= moment(i['startDate']);
let diff = end.diff(start, 'days')
console.log(diff);
if(diff >= 7){
newArray.push(i);
}
}
console.log(newArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```